# Why is 'a' used here? What is this type of usage called in English grammar?

Tags: grammar, articles

The sentence is : 'We do not need a corrupt IMF.'

Why is there 'a' before the proper noun, IMF?

Comment: Perhaps you should ask in http://ell.stackexchange.com

Comment: It's a ghost protocol 'a'

Comment: Related: [indefinite article plus proper name in organizational (i.e. business or bureaucracy) contexts](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/214838/indefinite-article-plus-proper-name-in-organizational-i-e-business-or-bureaucr), on the ELL site: [When to use indefinite article “a(n)” when referring to a person with an adjective?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/124245)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [indefinite article plus proper name in organizational (i.e. business or bureaucracy) contexts](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/214838/indefinite-article-plus-proper-name-in-organizational-i-e-business-or-bureaucr)

Answer (score 2):

Basic grammar questions get a warmer welcome at [ell.stackexchange.com](http://ell.stackexchange.com) but the answer is,

within the context of the statement, **the IMF is being treated as a common noun** and "a corrupt IMF" is being contrasted with other IMFs (specifically, "honest", "fair", "decent", &c. IMFs). *We do not need the corrupt IMF* would mean that the only IMF is a corrupt one; *We do not need corrupt IMF* inaccurately makes 'corrupt' part of its name and is a grammatical mistake. The phrasing being used means that the IMF has a range of approaches it may or does take; out of those, the corrupt one isn't welcomed.